# PHP Mysql PDO number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I've looked around here but can't seem to find an answer to my problem.

This is the first time I've used PDO and so am a complete newbie to it.

I have a load of data split into 2 tables and want to merge them into one, there are other ways of doing this, but without going into the complicated reasons why I am trying to do it this way...

I generate a recordset of the table I want to copy data from

construct my statement

run it in a loop

but I get the following error

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match the number of tokens
```

I've gone through and triple checked I have the same amount of variables so why "tokens don't match I dont know" like I said am very new to this so am probably missing something the pros would consider as obvious.

- It's probably worth mentioning that I am not adding to every single column in the table, there are other columns but I have left them out of the prepared statement...
  Heres my  code:

  ```
  //$dbh = new PDO($hostname_Seriously,  $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=seriouslysoulful_summers', $username_Seriously, $password_Seriously);
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO records_rec (oldid_rec, firstname_rec, artist_rec, aside_rec, bside_rec, label_rec, condition_rec, genere_rec, price_rec, collection_rec, active_rec, info_rec, notes_rec, order_rec, alabelimage_rec, blabelimage_rec, asound_rec, bsound_rec, featured_rec, format_rec) 
  VALUES (:oldid_rec, :firstname_rec, :artist_rec, :aside_rec, :bside_rec, :label_rec, :condition_rec, :genere_rec, :price_rec, :collection_rec, :active_rec, :info_rec, :notes_rec, :order_rec, :alabelimage_rec, :blabelimage_rec, asound_rec, bsound_rec, :featured_rec, :format_rec)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':oldid_rec', $id);
  $stmt->bindParam(':firstname_rec', $firstname);
  $stmt->bindParam(':artist_rec', $artist);
  $stmt->bindParam(':aside_rec',$aside);
  $stmt->bindParam(':bside_rec',$bside);
  $stmt->bindParam(':label_rec',$label);
  $stmt->bindParam(':condition_rec',$condition);
  $stmt->bindParam(':genere_rec',$genere);
  $stmt->bindParam(':price_rec',$price);
  $stmt->bindParam(':collection_rec',$collection);
  $stmt->bindParam(':active_rec',$active);
  $stmt->bindParam(':info_rec',$info);
  $stmt->bindParam(':notes_rec',$notes);
  $stmt->bindParam(':order_rec',$order);
  $stmt->bindParam(':alabelimage_rec',$alabel);
  $stmt->bindParam(':blabelimage_rec',$blabel);
  $stmt->bindParam(':asound_rec',$asound);
  $stmt->bindParam(':bsound_rec',$bsound);
  $stmt->bindParam(':featured_rec',$featured);
  $stmt->bindParam(':format_rec',$format);
  $reccount = 0;
  //do{
  $id = $row_rs_original['id_prod'];
  $firstname = 
  mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['firstname_prod']);
  $artist = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['artist_prod']);
  $aside = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['a_side_prod']);
  $bside = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['b_side_prod']);
  $label = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['label_prod']);
  $condition = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['condition_prod']);
  $genere = $row_rs_original['genre_prod'];
  $price = $row_rs_original['price_prod'];
  $collection = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['collection_prod']);
  $active = $row_rs_original['active_prod'];
  $info = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['info_prod']);
  $notes = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['notes_prod']);
  $order = $row_rs_original['order_prod'];
  $alabel = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['labelimage_A_prod']);
  $blabel = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['labelimage_B_prod']);
  $asound = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['soundfile_A_prod']);
  $bsound = mysql_real_escape_string($row_rs_original['soundfile_B_prod']);
  $featured = $row_rs_original['featured_prod'];
  $format = $row_rs_original['format_prod'];

  $stmt->execute();

      $reccount = $reccount +1;
  //} while ($row_rs_original = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_original));
  echo($reccount." - records added...");
  ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Missing colons

```
:blabelimage_rec, **:**asound_rec, **:**bsound_rec, :featured_rec, :format_rec
```

Answer (score 18):

Looks like Mark Baker already answered your question, but I wanted to add a couple of tips that have helped me out a lot.

**PDO Doesn't Need `mysql_escape_string`**
As long as everything going into your query that deals with user input is using a prepared statement (like you are above) you don't need to escape the input with `mysql_real_escape_string`[1].

```
// Don't worry about SQL injection since all of the user 
// defined inputs are being escaped by the PDO package
$sql = "INSERT INTO "
     .   "`users` "
     . "SET "
     .   "`name` = :name";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':name', $name);
$query->execute();
```

But DO be aware that SQL injection is still possible if you aren't binding user input:

```
// SQL injection can totally happen here
$sql = "INSERT INTO "
     .   "`users` "
     . "SET "
     .   "`name` = $name";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
```

[1] http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

**Try to Make Your SQL as Short as Possible**
For simple SQL statements, the shorter it is, the easier it is to maintain and you're less likely to make mistakes.  You could use an alternative INSERT syntax[2]:

```
INSERT INTO 
  `users`
SET
  `name` = 'Steve';
```

is equivalent to:

```
INSERT INTO 
  `users`
  (
    `name`
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'Steve'
  );
```

That means for big statements like yours, you can effectively *half* its size because you don't need to repeat all of the column names:

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO "
      .   "`records_rec` "
      . "SET "
      .   "`oldid_rec`       = :oldid_rec, "
      .   "`firstname_rec`   = :firstname_rec, " 
      .   "`artist_rec`      = :artist_rec, " 
      .   "`aside_rec`       = :aside_rec, "
      .   "`bside_rec`       = :bside_rec, "
      .   "`label_rec`       = :label_rec, "
      .   "`condition_rec`   = :condition_rec, " 
      .   "`genere_rec`      = :genere_rec, "
      .   "`price_rec`       = :price_rec, "
      .   "`collection_rec`  = :collection_rec, "
      .   "`active_rec`      = :active_rec, "
      .   "`info_rec`        = :info_rec, "
      .   "`notes_rec`       = :notes_rec, "
      .   "`order_rec`       = :order_rec, "
      .   "`alabelimage_rec` = :alabelimage_rec, "
      .   "`blabelimage_rec` = :blabelimage_rec, "
      .   "`asound_rec`      = :asound_rec, "
      .   "`bsound_rec`      = :bsound_rec, "
      .   "`featured_rec`    = :featured_rec, "
      .   "`format_rec`      = :format_rec";

$dbh = new PDO(<info goes here>);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql); 

// Bind your params here...
```

[2] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

**Do Make Your SQL Statements Multi-line and Pretty**

I started formatting my SQL statements to be multi-lined (like above) and ever since I've had WAY fewer errors like this.  It *does* take up a lot of room, but I think in the end it's worth it.  By making everything line up, it makes errors stick out like a sore thumb.

Happy coding!