# What's wrong with this PHP PDO statement for SQL insert?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I've already got username, password and other variables stored, but I keep getting an error "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens" in this line:

```
$database->query(
    'INSERT INTO users_inactive(verCode, username, password, email, date, type) 
    VALUES (:vercode, :username, :password, :email, :date, :type)', 
    array(
        ':vercode' => $verCode, 
        ':username' => $username, 
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':email' => $email, 
        ':date' => $date, 
        ':type'=>'customer')
);
```

Is there anything wrong with it? I've made sure each of these columns is available in my `user_inactive` table.

This is the $database wrapper function:

```
    public function query($query, $bind = null, $fetch = 'FETCH_ASSOC') {
    /* Prepare the query statement */
    $this->statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    /* Bind each value supplied from $bind */
    if($bind != null) {
        foreach($bind as $select => $value) {
            /* For each type of value give the appropriate param */
            if(is_int($value)) {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_INT; 
            } elseif(is_bool($value)) {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            } elseif(is_null($value)) {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            } elseif(is_string($value)) {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            } else {
                $param = FALSE;
            }
            /* Bid value */
            if($param) {
                $this->statement->bindValue($select, $value, $param);
            }
        }
    }
    /* Execute Query & check for any errors */
    if(!$this->statement->execute()){
        $result = array(
            1 => 'false',
            2 => '<b>[DATABASE] Error - Query:</b> There was an error in sql syntax',
        );
        return $result;
    }
    /* Return all content */
    if($fetch == 'FETCH_ASSOC') {
        $result = $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } elseif($fetch == 'FETCH_BOTH') {
        $result = $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    } elseif($fetch == 'FETCH_LAZY') {
        $result = $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
    } elseif($fetch == 'FETCH_OBJ') {
        $result = $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    } elseif($fetch == 'fetchAll') {
        $result = $this->statement->fetchAll();
    }
    return $result;
}
  }
```

Taken from Tutis Login.

Comment: This is some PDO statement wrapper class which executes a `query()` method with parameters, rather than `PDO::query()`?

Comment: yes it's a wrapper class. it was working fine just a few days ago, I can't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Without seeing the method definition, we can't really help.

Comment: Looks like your wrapper class mess with query or parameter list.

Comment: Just added the wrapper class's code. There can't be anything wrong with it though, because it was working fine a little while ago and I never changed it.

Comment: Isn't `date` a reserved word (and should as such be encapsulated in ` ?) (This goes for all your field names)

Comment: Side thought - you'd better replace those `if .. elseif ... elseif ... else` with `switch`

Comment: do you get this error with all queries or just this one?

Answer (score 0):

Just some clues,You are probably missing some colons. Check out here

[PHP Mysql PDO number of bound variables does not match number of tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331291/php-mysql-pdo-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-match-number-of-tokens)

Or probably there is some case sensitive going on on your colons

Comment: I know... I checked the colons... can't figure out what's wrong. When exactly are colons needed or not needed?

Comment: Are you parsing the date as string?

Comment: No, `$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());`

Comment: and verCode the C must be capital right? because you have it with lower case in the array

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in your wrapper function. `PDO::PARAM_NULL == 0`, so this value does not pass through

```
if($param) {
    ...
}
```

So you do not call bindValue() for NULL values. Instead, use:

```
if ($param !== FALSE) {
    ...
}
```

**EDIT** - reading again your code, this would be better code of the foreach() block, producing less cryptic error messages in the future :)

```
    foreach($bind as $select => $value) {
        /* For each type of value give the appropriate param */
        if(is_int($value)) {
            $param = PDO::PARAM_INT; 
        } elseif(is_bool($value)) {
            $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        } elseif(is_null($value)) {
            $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
        } elseif(is_string($value)) {
            $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        } else {
            // Report error about invalid type and return from the function
            ...
        }
        // we should bind every value from $bind array, unconditionally!
        $this->statement->bindValue($select, $value, $param);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Give this a shot:

```
<?php
$sql = $database->prepare(
'INSERT INTO users_inactive(verCode, username, password, email, date, type) 
VALUES (:vercode, :username, :password, :email, :date, :type)');
$sql->execute(array(
    'vercode' => $verCode, 
    'username' => $username, 
    'password' => $password, 
    'email' => $email, 
    'date' => $date, 
    'type'=>'customer')
);
```

Comment: `$database` is not PDO object. It's a custom object.

Comment: Didn't see that. I have had a similar problem, the only way I could fix it was to use `?` instead of `:xxx`.