# PDO: Number of bound variables does not match the number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

PHP/SQL Code:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * 
FROM  `jobs` 
WHERE  `city` = :city
AND  `district` = :district
AND  `type` = :type
AND (
CONVERT(  `id` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  '% :keyword %'
OR CONVERT(  `owner` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  '% :keyword %'
OR CONVERT(  `title` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  '% :keyword %'
OR CONVERT(  `city` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  '% :keyword %'
OR CONVERT(  `district` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  '% :keyword %'
OR CONVERT(  `type` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  '% :keyword %'
OR CONVERT(  `payrate` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  '% :keyword %'
OR CONVERT(  `hours` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  '% :keyword %'
OR CONVERT(  `description` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  '% :keyword %'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30");

$sth->bindParam(':city', $city);
$sth->bindParam(':district', $district);
$sth->bindParam(':type', $type);
$sth->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword);
$sth->execute();
```

Seems to be one of my tokens/variables isn't "bound" properly? Any ideas where/how to correct?

I'm guessing I need to escape something somewhere for the variable to work correctly however I am fairly newish to PDO and the way it's laid out.

Thanks.

Comment: I usually get this when one of my parameters values are `null`, `var_dump()` your  values: `$city, $district, $keyword` ect..

Comment: Didn't realise a NULL value could cause that, looks like both solutions corrected the issue, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Mysql PDO number of bound variables does not match number of tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331291/php-mysql-pdo-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-match-number-of-tokens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the quotes around `:keyword` and moving the `%` wildcards to your `bindParam` call.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * 
FROM  `jobs` 
WHERE  `city` = :city
AND  `district` = :district
AND  `type` = :type
AND (
CONVERT(  `id` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  :keyword
OR CONVERT(  `owner` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  :keyword
OR CONVERT(  `title` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  :keyword
OR CONVERT(  `city` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  :keyword
OR CONVERT(  `district` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  :keyword
OR CONVERT(  `type` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  :keyword
OR CONVERT(  `payrate` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  :keyword
OR CONVERT(  `hours` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  :keyword
OR CONVERT(  `description` 
USING utf8 ) LIKE  :keyword
)
LIMIT 0 , 30");

$sth->bindParam(':city', $city);
$sth->bindParam(':district', $district);
$sth->bindParam(':type', $type);
$sth->bindParam(':keyword', "%$keyword%");
$sth->execute();
```