# PDO Query throws a fatal error saying bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This script has form where user data get entered in this form there a check box which is used to mark if that user is a team leader. And I use a another script to check if that team has team leader or not if that team has a leader the team leader check box will be disabled.

This is the form:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: SiNUX
 * Date: 4/6/2017
 * Time: 3:41 PM
 */

session_start();
include_once("../iConnect/handShake.php");

$getUserRole = "SELECT * FROM userroles ORDER BY urId ASC";
$getUserRoleQuery = $dbConnect -> query($getUserRole);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Timer User Creation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Style Sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/main.css">

    <!-- Java Scripts -->
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/svrTimeDate.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/reload.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/setMsg.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/userCreatFunctions.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/multiScript.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/getIds.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="pauseLoad4()">
    <div id="divCenter" class="box">
        <label id="userName">Hello <?php echo $_SESSION["fName"]." ".$_SESSION["lName"]; ?></label><br><br>
        <label id="uId" hidden>1</label>
        <div style="width: 166px; position: absolute; left: 642px; top: 20px; height: 44px;">
            <img src="../../images/logo.png" width="142" height="33">
        </div>
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <label id="date" style="margin-left: 50px;"></label><br><br>
        <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" style="margin-left: 10px;" onkeyup="checkEmpty();">
        <label for="lName" style="margin-left: 8px;">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" style="margin-left: 10px;" onkeyup="checkEmpty();" disabled>
        <label for="uName" style="margin-left: 8px;">User Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="uName" name="uName" style="margin-left: 7px;" onkeyup="checkEmpty();" disabled><br><br>
        <label for="pWord1" style="margin-left: 8px;" >Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pWord1" name="pWord1" style="margin-left: 17px;" onkeyup="checkLength();" disabled>
        <label for="pWord2" style="margin-left: 8px;">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pWord2" name="pWord2" style="margin-left: 8px;" onkeyup="checkPass();" disabled>
        <label for="uTeam" style="margin-left: 8px;">Team</label>
        <select name="uTeam" id="uTeam" style="width: 170px;" onchange="teamId(this.id);enableRoles();" disabled>
            <option></option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="uTeamId" id="uTeamId" hidden><br><br>
        <div id="userRoles">
            <label for="userRoles">User Role:</label><label for="uAttrib" style="margin-left: 250px;">User Attributes:</label><br>
            <?php while ($row = $getUserRoleQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="<?php echo $row["urId"]; ?>" disabled><?php echo $row["userRole"]; }?>
                <input type="checkbox" id="tl" name="tl" value="yes" style="margin-left: 120px;" disabled>Team Leader
        </div>
        <label id="msgID" hidden></label>
        <div id="msg"></div>
        <div id="sbmBtns">
            <input type="button" value="Reset" name="reset" id="reset" class="btn" onclick="resetForm()">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn" onclick="pauseLoad3();" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All the data collected is directed to my PHP processing page this page also has 2 parts first query executes and users details in to a database called userlogin.

Second parts is executed after the first one which take the last added id from userlogin database then it will be updated in my teams database where user ID and set a value to designate if that particular team has a leader or not.

My first part executes with out any error but the second part throws and error **"invalid parameter number number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in"**.

I tried echoing all the data which is set in side that if function all was echoed but still this gives me that error I really can't find what I'm doing wrong please can some help me below is my PHP code.

PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: SiNUX
 * Date: 4/7/2017
 * Time: 12:15 PM
 */

include_once("../iConnect/handShake.php");

if (isset($_REQUEST["tl"])){
    //Have to use the intermediate variable as work around to warning massage
    // Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference
    $intPword = md5($_REQUEST["pword"]);

    $addUser = "INSERT INTO userlogin (uCreateDate, createdBy, fName, lName, uName, pWord, uTeam, uRole) VALUES (:uCreateDate, :uId, :fName, :lName, :uName, :pWord, :uTeam, :uRole)";
    $addUserQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($addUser);
    $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':uCreateDate', $_REQUEST["udate"]);
    $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':uId', $_REQUEST["uId"]);
    $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':fName', $_REQUEST["fName"]);
    $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':lName', $_REQUEST["lName"]);
    $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':uName', $_REQUEST["uName"]);
    $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':pWord', $intPword);
    $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':uTeam', $_REQUEST["team"]);
    $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':uRole', $_REQUEST["uRole"]);

    if ($addUserQuery -> execute()){
        $lastUid = $dbConnect -> lastInsertId();

        if (isset($lastUid)){
            $addTl = "UPDATE teams SET tlName = :tlName, tlSet = :tlSet WHERE tId = :tId";
            $addTlQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($addTl);
            $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':tId', $_REQUEST["team"]);
            $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':tlName', $lastUid);
            $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':tlSet', $_REQUEST["tl"]);
            echo $lastUid. " Last ID<br>";
            echo $_REQUEST["tl"]. " TL<br>";
            echo $_REQUEST["team"];

            if ($addUserQuery -> execute()){
                echo "1";
            }else{
                echo "11";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "10";
    }

}else{
    echo "3";
}
```

**UPDATE:** This is not DUPLICATE of some other post as marked look at content it was a mistake which I over saw I was binding values to the wrong query first of you people need read this before flagging. And mentioned link didn't solve my issue it's not even close to what I'm asking. Error is the same but the problem differs.

**UPDATE:** I just want to say sorry for making a big rant in comments section yesterday I'm really sorry acted very immature I was frustrated that led to this I'm sorry again.

Comment: `bindParam` in second query must be called on `$addTlQuery`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Mysql PDO number of bound variables does not match number of tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331291/php-mysql-pdo-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-match-number-of-tokens)

Comment: Did you even read before flagging this @MasivuyeCokile you were more than help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is with this code. You are binding the params to different query object.

```
$addTl = "UPDATE teams SET tlName = :tlName, tlSet = :tlSet WHERE tId = :tId";
            $addTlQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($addTl);
            $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':tId', $_REQUEST["team"]);
            $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':tlName', $lastUid);
            $addUserQuery -> bindParam(':tlSet', $_REQUEST["tl"]);
            echo $lastUid. " Last ID<br>";
            echo $_REQUEST["tl"]. " TL<br>";
            echo $_REQUEST["team"];

            if ($addUserQuery -> execute()){
                echo "1";
            }else{
                echo "11";
            }
```

You need to update the `$addUserQuery` to `$addTlQuery`

Comment: Damn really thank you I really didn't see that I could kill my self right now.

Comment: I would have if the system let me was unable to do that for 5m some reason and I went have my lunch so stop being such a ...

Comment: @Jack, a little uncalled for with the remark.. He was merely suggesting you vote it helpful so it'll help other people viewing this topic who's in the same situation.

Comment: I already did, tried to mark it prior to his uncalled for comment my friend. For some reason stacks kept saying I had to wait 5 minutes and it was counting down so while waiting I went for lunch to mark it afterwards when came back I saw that I know what to do in Stacks OP helped I'm glad he did.