# click button to display the next record in database (Limit)

Tags: php, pdo, pagination, limit

whats the wrong in my code .. i try to click next button to display the next record in database .. but when i clicked nothing happen

this is my function to fetch record

```
  public function getBooks()
{
    $limit = 1;
    //SELECT loginUser.username, Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username="loay";
    $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username LIMIT $limit";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->execute([
        ':username' => $this->username
    ]);
    $result = $statment->fetchAll();

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Books</th>
    </tr>";
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

}

And this is my code in index.php

```
  if($object->getBooks()){
  if( isset($_POST['next'])){

    $limit +=1;  
}
```

}

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: Are you getting $limit in index.php?

Comment: yes for one record.. but when i click on next button the record removed like when i reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

You only have number of records to be fetched, you didn't give the start argument.

Your query should be `$query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username LIMIT $start, $limit"`

Please note `$start, $limit` after `LIMIT`

Then your code should be

```
 if( isset($_POST['next'])){

     $start +=1;  
 }
```

**EDIT:
I just figured you're fetching records by username, I further assume each username is unique. In that case paging won't work. Since there's only one row per username. Try a query like `$query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id LIMIT $start, $limit"`
Without the where clause.

You must use your `WHERE loginUser.username=:username` only when you're fetching records added by the provided `loginUser.username`

Comment: thank you for your response .. but it still not work.

Comment: should i declare $limit = 1 before the select statement like this :  

` $limit = 1; $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username LIMIT $start, $limit";`

Comment: And yes, your variables should be initialized before you use them in the query. Initially `$start = 0;` and `$limit = 1;`

Comment: any other help please!?

Comment: If you haven't solved this, the problem is probably your prepared statement, please attach your `execute` arguments. Maybe the number of bound variables doesn't match the number of provided tokens https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331291/php-mysql-pdo-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-match-number-of-tokens